# Heroku uploads from multipart/form-data form

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, multipartform-data

Does anybody know something about obstacles that could be meet in way of uploading images in express application. Imagine that  you use some npm package as a middleware (I used lot of them). Imagine that all was carefully set up and there are no errors in heroku logs or elsewhere. Also `req.files<name_of_the_input_for _files_upload>.path` returns from the console, but if to try `heroku run bash -a my_application` and then `cd / && find . | grep <name from path>` there will be not found.
What I tried investigating my problem:
I cloned [this repo](https://github.com/xfakehopex/node-file-uploads) and uploaded to Heroku. The author of this project has working demo also on heroku, but when I deployed it. It brokes after the uploading. I created folders and changed the access rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku uses an ephemeral file system. When you `heroku run`, you're not sshing into the same server that's running your app. A new, ephemeral (temporary) dyno is spun up for you, and that's what you're working inside of.

Imagine you have an app with 5 servers. A user uploads a file to one of them. If you ssh into one of the servers, you only have a 1 in 5 chance of seeing the file.

Answer (score 1):

The only real way to do file uploads in Heroku is to write those files somewhere else.  S3, Google Drive, whatever.  Someplace that actually keeps a persistent file store.  There's a few addins for it, or you can use middleware that you just can configure to push directly to your S3 account (for example).